# fill in NA by outcome of formula between previous and following non-NA values in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr, na

I have the following dataframe:

```
day <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, 10, 11)
totalItems <- c(700, NA, 32013, NA, NA, NA, 39599, NA, NA, NA, 107542)
df <- data.frame(day, totalItems)
```

I need to create another variable/column where NAs are replaced by the outcome of a formula: (following available non NA - previous available non NA) / (row number of following non NA - row number of previous non NA), in order to get this final dataframe :

```
day <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, 10, 11)
totalItems <- c(700, NA, 32013, NA, NA, NA, 39599, NA, NA, NA, 107542)
estimatedDaily <- c(700, 15656, 15656, 1897, 1897, 1897, 1897, 16986, 16986, 16986, 16986)
df.new <- data.frame(day, totalItems, estimatedDaily)
```

I tried to juggle with `tidyr::replace_na()` but I couldn't figure out how to define the formula to be able to identify the previous and the following available non NA.
Many thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create groups in your data based on presence of `NA` values.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- df %>% mutate(group = cumsum(lag(!is.na(totalItems), default = TRUE)))
df1

#   day totalItems group
#1    1        700     1
#2    2         NA     2
#3    3      32013     2
#4    4         NA     3
#5    5         NA     3
#6    6         NA     3
#7    7      39599     3
#8    8         NA     4
#9    9         NA     4
#10  10         NA     4
#11  11     107542     4
```

Keep only the rows in `df1` which has value in it apply the formula to each group and join it with `df1` to get same number of rows back.

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  slice(n()) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  transmute(group, estimatedDaily = (totalItems - lag(totalItems, default = 0))/
                                    (day - lag(day, default = 0))) %>%
  left_join(df1, by = 'group') %>%
  select(-group)

#  estimatedDaily   day totalItems
#            <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1           700      1        700
# 2         15656.     2         NA
# 3         15656.     3      32013
# 4          1896.     4         NA
# 5          1896.     5         NA
# 6          1896.     6         NA
# 7          1896.     7      39599
# 8         16986.     8         NA
# 9         16986.     9         NA
#10         16986.    10         NA
#11         16986.    11     107542
```

Comment: Thank you. It works fine. However, I noticed that it does not work if the `day` variable is formatted as a date. Any suggestion to fix this ?

Comment: In that case you can turn `day` variable to number by doing `day = day - first(day) + 1`

Comment: Just received the dataset from the client, and there is a difference from the original I shared here. Besides the fact that it has hundred of thousands rows, it also has an additional `Country` column. I guess I should add a `group_by(Country)` somewhere in your code... but so far I am not able to find the right code. Sorry to bother... I am quite a newbie ! Thank you

Comment: @Sal Yes, you need to add `group_by(country)` to create `group` i.e `df1 <- df %>% group_by(country) %>% mutate(group -...`. Also `df1 %>%
  group_by(group, country) %>%....`